# Center Aling a Dynamic Width Table's Caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I Have a Caption with Dynamic Width, and i Want it in the center of the `table`, but `inline-block` isnt working right, the `inline` make it in the center of the `td`, not of all the table, How can i make it in the center of the table? Here is a example of this html:

```
<table class="hours-table" style="width: 100%;" border="0"><caption>Title</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1_1</td>
<td>1_2</td>
<td>1_3</td>
<td>1_4</td>
<td>1_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2_1</td>
<td>2_2</td>
<td>2_3</td>
<td>2_4</td>
<td>2_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3_1</td>
<td>3_2</td>
<td>3_3</td>
<td>3_4</td>
<td>3_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4_1</td>
<td>4_2</td>
<td>4_3</td>
<td>4_4</td>
<td>4_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5_1</td>
<td>5_2</td>
<td>5_3</td>
<td>5_4</td>
<td>5_5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Like this you want http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EDU/

Comment: Kinda, the problem is that i Have a Background in the Caption, so it cant have full width, beacause it wouldn't get right with the BG, understand?

Comment: Then It Alings just with the td, not with the full table, take a look in it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EDU/1/

Comment: Is this ok....http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EDU/2/

Comment: I want the Background just where is the Caption, not in the full Caption's Line, so the Width must be dynamic, understand? Thanks a lot Again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13751/discussion-between-svs-and-henrique-foletto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be both vertically and horizontally aligned in the center, you could use the following CSS:

```
table { position: relative; }
caption {
    ​position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -0.5em -10px; /* Change the -10px part depending on length of title */
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/)

If you only want it to be horizontally aligned (at the top of the table, you could use:

```
caption { text-align: center; }
```

​
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/1/)

**Edit:** Here is a solution that will allow a background behind a centered caption but also create a white background behind just the text part of the caption:

*HTML*

```
<caption>Title</caption>
```

*CSS*

```
div { background: url('background_image.jpg') repeat; }
caption {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
span { background: white; }
```

*JS*

```
$(function() {
    var caption = $('caption');
    caption.html('<span>' + caption.html() + '</span>');
    });​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/5/)

Comment: I cant have it with full width, just center aligned, because I'm going to use a Background, understand?

Thanks a lot Guy!

Comment: I cant have it with full width, just center aligned, because I'm going to use a Background, understand?

Comment: And how could I change the margin depending on length if the length is Dynamic?

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto is the issue that you want the background to appear behind the caption? If so, then having a dynamic width may still block part of the background. Is this closer to what you want? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/2/)

Comment: The First Example you gave me was very nice, but I cant have the length of it, And I wouldnt have problems with Bakcground Color. Thanks again!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you want at this point. What exactly are the requirements? Does this look like what you want? [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/3/) This shows the table background, and you can see a white background behind *just* the caption text (and not across the whole row). The text is also centered in the table.

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot, this one was nice, but, being it WP, i Cant change the Default Table Template, that is the one i First showed to you, But, I'm Trying to use JS and jQUery to put the span in the caption, but for some reason it isnt going right, take a look: $('caption').prepend('<span>').append('</span>');  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto you can try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/4/). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It works AWESOME in Google Chrome, but in Firefox it doesnt create just 1 span, it create 5! Anyway Thanks a LOT again!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto good to hear it's working! There was a small typo in my last link that was causing it to create extra `span` elements. It is corrected here: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/5/). I will update my answer with the working solution since it looks like we've found an answer to your problem.

Comment: AWESOME, The problem wasnt that, I aplyed it as Javascript, but it is Jquery, now it is Working just magnificently, I simplified the Jquery for a more simple Use, see it Here: http://jsfiddle.net/TxDdv/7/ . THANKS A LOT!!! You are AWESOME!